# Unblocking hardware switch WiFi

Tags: wireless

On my Toshiba laptop, Ubuntu does not seem to be able to hard blocking/unblocking the WiFi card.

I dual-boot with Windows 7 and usually I leave WiFi on. However, yesterday I disabled WiFi while using Windows and when I rebooted into Ubuntu, I couldn't unblock the WiFi. I had to reboot into Windows to re-enable the WiFi.

`rfkill unblock all` and `rfkill block all` do not work for the hardware switch. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> toggles the soft block of the WiFi, whereas on Windows it toggles the hardware switch.

This is the result of `lspci | grep Network`

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

Is there a way to enable Ubuntu to hard block/unblock the WiFi card?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in udev

Hummm, Suspend -> resume for me it works

It also cured the fact my altgr key was not functioning

My guess is event listener is stacking events and there is a lock preventing the queue from depiling the events. Suspend -> resume seems to «unfreeze» the queue...

I had a lot of problems related to this one... I guess taking the action (like rfkill unblock all) might be necessary too...

Comment: Could you add a link to the bug?